# React native RTCRootView.h not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to use React native and I am getting an error in xcode that says "Lexical or preprocessor error 'RTCRootView.h' not found." I have checked and this file is in the framework folder and I have tried moving it into the project as well and still have not been able to eliminate the error and successfully build.

Comment: Can you provide a little code? At least can you show how you import framework header to your class?

Comment: i'm importing the header like this: `#import "RCTRootView.h"` and i'm actually using the example app from [here](http://react-components.com/component/react-native-swipeout).

Comment: If you use react-native as *.framework you possibly need import it in another way, something like this: #import <React/React.h>. I am not sure about naming. Just put framework name instead of "React".

Comment: Does anyone know what "RCT" stands for?

Comment: @MichaelL. RCT is an abbreviation of ReaCT

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the `example` directory, run `npm install` to install the dependencies.
Then, open `swipeoutExample.xcodeproj` and run.

[react-native-swipeout#15](https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout/issues/15).

#### edit (2015-10-12):

react-native-swipeout has been updated to use the latest react-native including `./ios` and `./android` directories.

- iOS: Open the xcode project in the `./ios` directory and run it.
- Android: Start a simulator, then run `react-native run-android` in project root directory. *(note: swipeout is currently incompatible with Android, but will be soon.)*

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. I used npm to download so it didn't even occur to me to use it to install dependencies. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Running `npm install` might work for some people, but it didn't work for me.

What worked for me was in XCode > Product > Clean [image: XCode > Product > Clean]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might be because the node_modules folder is missing in your project directory.

- Move the node_modules folder to your project
- run npm install in your project directory

Answer (score 0):

Just faced with the same error. In my case it was because of typing error. I replaced RTCRootView.h with RCTRootView.h (RCT is an abbreviation of ReaCT).